# How to pass custom message into 404 blade in Laravel 5

Tags: http-status-code-404, laravel-5

In a certain route, if a cat cannot be found by its id, I return a 404 with a custom message:

```
App::abort(404, 'Invalid cat id');
```

I want to pass custom messages like the one above into Laravel's 404 blade but I cannot figure out how to get this message into it. It seems I will have to hack some of Laravel's code to do it.

I have also tried this, which does display the custom message but the http status code is 200 instead of 404, which is not what I want:

```
view('errors.404')->with('message', 'Invalid cat id');
```

I feel like there must be a simpler, more standardized way to do something this elementary in Laravel. What is the correct way?

Comment: tried using flash message Session::flash('message','your message') and using {{Session::get('message')}} in the 404 error page. that's my solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

`return response()->view('errors.404', ['message' => 'Invalid cat id'], 404);`

Comment: Thank you. Geez, so many different ways to do things in Laravel. Kind of like Zend in that way.

Answer (score 4):

Everywhere says you can do a simple

```
abort(404, 'Invalid cat id');
```

But I haven't found that in the docs. My solution:

```
View::share('message','Invalid cat id');
abort(404);
```

This will share de $message variable with all the views and you'll have a 404 HTTP code. Then just do this inside 404.blade.php file:

```
{{ $message }}
```

Answer (score 0):

I simply do like this :

```
return view('errors.404', ['msg' => 'some message']);
```

And in the view (in **404.blade.php** file) write :

```
{{ $msg }}
```

Then you will see in the view :

`some message`